# How do you move a turtle horizontally without changing it's heading?

Tags: python, python-2.7

[Gravity Code][1]
I am making a game called Gravity code. And when the turtle catches falling "code", I need it to move horizontally, but to do that I have to turn the turtle to the right, move forward, then turn left. Because `settiltangle` doesn't work in trinket.

```
import turtle

user = turtle.Turtle()
user.speed("fastest")
user.shape("turtle")
user.fillcolor("white")
user.left(90)
user.penup()
user.goto(0, -192)

def left():
  user.left(90)
  user.forward(10)
  user.right(90)

def right():
  user.right(90)
  user.forward(10)
  user.left(90)

# --- events ---

screen.onkey(left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(left, 'a')
screen.onkey(right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(right, 'd')
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: I might as well point out that this sort of behavior is going to get you suspended. Please read the links that I shared about for how to go about deleting your content and/or account in the appropriate fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# --- imports ---

import turtle
import random

# --- variables ---

x_title = -70
y_title = 60
game_title = "Gravity Code"
title = turtle.Turtle()
font_setup = ("Verdana", 25, "normal")
screen = turtle.Screen()

# --- main ---

screen.colormode(255)
title.speed("fastest")
title.hideturtle()
title.penup()
title.goto(x_title, y_title)

for i in range(len(game_title)):
    r = random.randint(1, 255)
    g = random.randint(1, 255)
    b = random.randint(1, 255)
    if game_title[i] != " ":
        title.color((r, g, b))
        x_title += 25
        title.write(game_title[i], font = font_setup)
        title.goto(x_title, y_title)
    else:
        x_title = -80
        y_title = 30
        title.goto(x_title, y_title)

# --- events ---

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: the effect that I added

Comment: Adjust it with x_title, align settings in font_setup, the font itself, and the time of change of position.